# Change currency depending upon IP

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, currency

I am working on a website where I need to show product price according to different country currency and if user want to change currency, he can and if he moved to different page, he currency remains as he selected previously (maybe a cookie).

Can you please direct me to right direction? I have found one link doing almost what I need but it does not save choosen currency on page refresh. http://curry.netyou.co.il/demo/

Here is one link what it does exactly:http://gusikowski-inc5583.myshopify.com/

Comment: What you want to use is session.

Comment: No, I have no preference of using session. Just want the final output.

Answer (score 1):

Use Locale class to get header from browser.

```
$loc = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $loc;
```

It will return locale of browser for example en_US or PL_pl

Read more on:

- http://php.net/locale
- http://php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php